# Cypher - the actors that participated in a movie of any of the top categories

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am beginning to use Neo4J and to get used to Cypher.
My graph contains 3 types of entities: actors, movies, categories

The edges are:

- an actor participate in a movie
- a movie contains a topic (a movie could have several categories)

I was able to write a query that display the topics of all the movies of an actor .

A demo of the graph and the query is set up in the neo4j console http://console.neo4j.org/?id=sm07j5

Now, I want to write a query that retrieves all the topics of an actor  and then the actors that participated in a movie of any of these topics categories: Is it possible to do it with a single query?
Or do I have to store first the top categories in a variable?

Does Cypher support variable definition from query results?

Comment: Can you share a sample data set or some data in a [Neo4j Console](http://console.neo4j.org/)?

Comment: Also, share with us the query you have wrote to get the top categories of an actor.

Comment: @BrunoPeres Here is the link to the neo4j console: http://console.neo4j.org/?id=sm07j5

Comment: I think you'll need to provide more details on exactly what you want. How do you want to limit/order in the query? How are you calculating top categories per actor, and are you limiting or ordering them? Do you want to limit/order the movies of those top categories? For that limited set of movies, do you want the collection of all actors that participated in those movies, or is that meant to be limited/ordered as well?

Comment: The purpose of my question was to understand how to use the result of a a part of the query as the input of the next part of the query. 
The logic of limit/order was not an essential part of the question. The question has been updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I correctly understand your requirement to "query that retrieves the **top** categories of an actor and then the actors that participated in a movie of any of these **top** categories" this would be simple answer if there were no this "**top** categories".

```
MATCH (Robin: Actor {name: 'Robin Williams'})-[:ACTS_IN]->(m:Movie)-[:IS_ABOUT]->(t:Topic)
WITH t MATCH (t:Topic)<-[:IS_ABOUT]-(r:Movie)<-[:ACTS_IN]-(a:Actor)
RETURN a, COLLECT(t)
```

Above query result:

```
(2:Actor {name:"Demi Moore"})     [(7:Topic {name:"Teenagers"})]
(1:Actor {name:"Tom Cruise"})     [(7:Topic {name:"Teenagers"})]
(3:Actor {name:"Tom Hanks"})      [(8:Topic {name:"School"})]
(0:Actor {name:"Robin Williams"}) [(8:Topic {name:"School"}), (7:Topic {name:"Teenagers"})]
```

As @InverseFalcon commented, you did not provide any info on how categories should be valued and ordered...

Comment: thanks for your answer.  
The purpose of my question was to understand how to use the result of a a part of the query as the input of the next part of the query. The logic of limit/order was not an essential part of the question. The question has been updated

Comment: So answer to your question "Is it possible to do it with a single query?" is obviously yes then. 
For using result from previous MATCH statement and passing it to the next, you use WITH clause. However entire cypher statement is considered single query.